# Unable to Start/Connect to MySQL 8.0 in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: mysql, netbeans

So I have the following problem. I'm trying to register **MySQL 8.0** from the services tab in **Netbeans 8.2.**

When doing so I enter all the Basic and Admin properties and it gets added but when I click on Start I get the following error:

*No enum constant com.mysql.cj.conf.PropertyDefinition.ZeroDatetimeBehavior.CONVERTTONULL*

[Here is a Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq1rJ.png)

I've been researching a lot and apparently I have to change some xml file that I don't know exactly where to find it.

Anyone has any idea about this?

I don't understand why it works when I use MySQL server 5.x but not with 8.x

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that netbeans doesn't support Mysql 8.0 server. 
It even says so in the official site that please select Mysql 5 server when installing.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html

**This is not the case anymore.** Please refer below as stated by @skomisa:

[Specified Class is not a Driver. Can't add MySQL Connector/J 8.0 to Netbeans 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433053/specified-class-is-not-a-driver-cant-add-mysql-connector-j-8-0-to-netbeans-8-0)

Comment: This answer is completely wrong: [1] MySQL 8.0 can definitely be run on NetBeans 8.2. See the accepted answer to [Can't add MySQL Connector/J 8.0 to Netbeans 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52433053/2985643) [2] Your claim that NetBeans documentation states that it "doesn't support Mysql 8.0 server" is completely false. The link you provide says nothing about MySQL 8. [3] The documentation you link to does not refer to MySQL 8 because MySQL8 did not exist when that documentation was written! Please correct or delete your answer. It is harmful.

Answer (score 1):

please update your mysql driver  from offical mysql website it about 8.01 but the current is old 5.0