# Specified Class is not a Driver. Can't add MySQL Connector/J 8.0 to Netbeans 8.0

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netbeans, netbeans-8, mysql-connector

I can't get MySQL 8.0 jdbc driver set up in Netbeans. Can anyone help?

My Netbeans 8.0 IDE was set up using an older version of the MySQL JDBC Driver, 5.1.23. I upgraded MySQL to 8.0 and am trying to setup a new JDBC Driver in Netbeans because the old driver isn't able to connect to the new DB (*see note at end).

These are the steps I followed.

**Step 1:** I removed the old mysql driver jar file from `D:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\ide\modules\ext` and copied the new `mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar` file and restarted the IDE.

**Step 2:** In the Services tab under `Databases` I right clicked on `Drivers` and `New Driver...`

[image: Netbeans Database Drivers]

**Step 3:** In the dialog box that shows up I click the `Add...` button and I select the new driver jar `D:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\ide\modules\ext\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar`

At this point the `Driver Class` automatically gets populated with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and I can't hit the `OK` button because there's a message `Specified class is not a driver (java.sql.Driver)`

[image]

I tried changing it to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver but it still gave the same message.

I decompiled com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from the jar file and got this:

```
package com.mysql.jdbc;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Driver
  extends com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
{
  public Driver()
    throws SQLException
  {}

  static
  {
    System.err.println("Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.");
  }
}
```

and for com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver I got this

```
package com.mysql.cj.jdbc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Driver
  extends NonRegisteringDriver
  implements java.sql.Driver
{
  public Driver()
    throws SQLException
  {}

  static
  {
    try
    {
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
    }
    catch (SQLException E)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
    }
  }
}
```

So com.mysql.jdbc.Driver extends com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver which implements java.sql.Driver so I don't know what the error is all about.

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this? I tried a 6.0 driver and got the same error. The 5 driver works but can't connect to DB.

- Side note. with the old 5 driver I was getting ClassCastException when trying to connect to database. BigInt can't be Cast to Long. When I changed the driver in the application to the new driver that problem went away.

Comment: Note that the MySQL Connector/J version 6.0 has never been released for GA, the only versions that exist where development/test releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am successfully using `mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar` as the driver for MySQL 8.0 on NetBeans 8.2, so it definitely works:

[image: mySqlDriver]

I don't see any obvious reason for your problem but there are some things you can try to resolve this:

- In your **New JDBC Driver** screenshot NetBeans is naming the driver ***MySQL (Connector/J driver) (1)***. Presumably that is because you already have a driver named ***MySQL (Connector/J driver)***, and your first screen shot confirms that. Why are you trying to add a second driver for MySQL? If there is no good reason, can you delete the old one, and then try adding the driver again?
- Check for multiple instances of the 8.0.12 driver, and delete any old MySQL 5.x and MySQL 8.x drivers in your filestore, unless you have good reason to keep any of them.
- The [download page for Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html) states *"We suggest that you use the MD5 checksums and GnuPG signatures to verify the integrity of the packages you download"*. Did you do that? It's unlikely but possible that you have a corrupt file. Also, note that you must select *"Platform Independent"* when downloading the driver for Windows.
- NetBeans might be caching something that's causing this problem. That's just a wild and desperate guess on my part, with no evidence at all to back it up, but you can easily and safely delete the cache to eliminate it as a possibility:

  - **Help > About**
  - Scroll down and locate the path of the **Cache directory**.
  - Shutdown NetBeans and delete that directory.
  - Start NetBeans and try again.
- Check the NetBeans Log for possible insight into the problem:

  - Repeat the attempt to create the driver.
  - **View > IDE Log** and review the most recent entries in the log.
- There might be an issue with NetBeans 8.0 since it is fairly old. Is it possible to upgrade to version 8.2 or 9.0?

---

**Update based on feedback in the comments from the OP:**

The OP reports that the cause of the problem was given by this message in the NetBeans log:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.db.explorer.dlg.AddDriverDialog]: Got an
exception trying to load class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver during search for
JDBC drivers in driver jar(s): java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0. Skipping
this class...
```

The **Connector/J 8.0** driver [requires Java 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-whats-new.html):

> It is a MySQL driver for the Java 8 platform. For Java 7 or earlier,
>   use Connector/J 5.1 instead.

So updating the default platform for NetBeans from JDK 7 to JDK 8 in **netBeans.conf** resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Can you please check and see if you have the jar in your [installpath]\ide\modules\ext directory? 1) I deleted old MySQl driver no luck 2) I checked in the netbeans installation directory only place was in etc dir and I deleted from there too. 3) I checked md5 it matches, 4) Cleared cache no luck 5) Ok found something. Will post as new comment.

Comment: Found culprit in log. Netbeans had default JDK set to Java7 changed netbeans_jdkhome in [netbeansinstallpath]\etc\netbeans.conf  to point to new JDK 8 installation directory From Log: INFO [org.netbeans.modules.db.explorer.dlg.AddDriverDialog]: Got an exception trying to load class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver during search for JDBC drivers in  driver jar(s): java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.  Skipping this class...

Comment: Can you please include the log entry I found and fix to your answer, move "Check netbeans log..." to the first thing to do and mention me in a comment when done and I'll accept the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: OK. I have updated my answer with your useful feedback. However, I didn't move the log review to the front of the list since apart from correcting typos I don't like making _in situ_ changes to an original answer. Instead, I have appended an update to the end of my answer.

Comment: Regarding _"Can you please check and see if you have the jar in your [installpath]\ide\modules\ext directory?"_, I checked, and I don't. The driver can reside anywhere; it does not have to be in that **ext** directory (although that is certainly a reasonable place to put it).

Answer (score 1):

Found that updating my Java version fixed it for me (from JDK 11 -> 18) since it seems the Java version the binary was compiled for was too new

Answer (score 0):

Use `Connection Properties` button and add a property with field name `serverTimezone` and value `UTC`.

This should work if error was caused by timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem of driver class, but when I checked the zip file mysql-connector-java-8.0.30, there is a second zip file within, then I used that second zip and solve the problem for Driver class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).